# Replace table column value in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I am using apache POI 3.7. I am trying to replace the value of a table column in a word document (docx). However, what I have done is it keeps appending the value of the current value in the document. But if a table column value is null, it places the value. Can you give me some thoughts how to resolve this. Below is the code I have done so far.

Thanks in advance.

```
package test.doc;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableCell;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableRow;

public class POIDocXTableTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        String fileName = "C:\\Test.docx";
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);
        List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();

        for (int x=0; x<paragraphs.size();x++)
        {
            XWPFParagraph paragraph = paragraphs.get(x);
            System.out.println(paragraph.getParagraphText());
        }
        List<XWPFTable> tables = document.getTables();
        for (int x=0; x<tables.size();x++)
        {
            XWPFTable table = tables.get(x);
            List<XWPFTableRow> tableRows = table.getRows();
            tableRows.remove(x);
            for (int r=0; r<tableRows.size();r++)
            {
                System.out.println("Row "+ (r+1)+ ":");
                XWPFTableRow tableRow = tableRows.get(r);
                List<XWPFTableCell> tableCells = tableRow.getTableCells();
                for (int c=0; c<tableCells.size();c++)
                {
                    System.out.print("Column "+ (c+1)+ ": ");
                    XWPFTableCell tableCell = tableCells.get(c);
                    //tableCell.setText("TAE");
                    String tableCellVal = tableCell.getText();
                    if ((c+1)==2){
                        if (tableCellVal!=null){
                            if (tableCellVal.length()>0){
                                 char c1 = tableCellVal.charAt(0);
                                 String s2 = "-TEST";
                                 char c2 = s2.charAt(0);
                                 String test = tableCell.getText().replace(tableCellVal,s2);
                                 tableCell.setText(test);
                            }else{
                                //tableCell.setText("NULL");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("tableCell.getText(" + (c) + "):" + tableCellVal);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        document.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with POI 3.8 beta 4? (or even better a recent nightly build?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to use apache POI 3.8.4 (Latest build) using the same code I have but its still appending the values. I found a link for replace but this it works for paragraph. Can anyone give some thoughts on how to do this in table cells? [link]http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Embed-string-data-to-docx-file-in-java-td3287560.html[link]

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it seems that it does not work for me when trying to replace text in paragraphs. Hence, I did this dangerous modification. Appreciate your comments:                  p.removeRun(i);
{
XWPFRun rB4=rs.get(i-1);
String textB4 = rB4.getText(0);
textB4 = StringUtils.remove(textB4, searchValue);
rB4.setText(textB4);
}

Answer (score 9):

The best solution to prevent styles in paragraphs and find search strings with different styles is this method:

```
  private long replaceInParagraphs(Map<String, String> replacements, List<XWPFParagraph> xwpfParagraphs) {
    long count = 0;
    for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : xwpfParagraphs) {
      List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();

      for (Map.Entry<String, String> replPair : replacements.entrySet()) {    
        String find = replPair.getKey();
        String repl = replPair.getValue();
        TextSegement found = paragraph.searchText(find, new PositionInParagraph());
        if ( found != null ) {
          count++;
          if ( found.getBeginRun() == found.getEndRun() ) {
            // whole search string is in one Run
           XWPFRun run = runs.get(found.getBeginRun());
           String runText = run.getText(run.getTextPosition());
           String replaced = runText.replace(find, repl);
           run.setText(replaced, 0);
          } else {
            // The search string spans over more than one Run
            // Put the Strings together
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            for (int runPos = found.getBeginRun(); runPos <= found.getEndRun(); runPos++) {
              XWPFRun run = runs.get(runPos);
              b.append(run.getText(run.getTextPosition()));
            }                       
            String connectedRuns = b.toString();
            String replaced = connectedRuns.replace(find, repl);

            // The first Run receives the replaced String of all connected Runs
            XWPFRun partOne = runs.get(found.getBeginRun());
            partOne.setText(replaced, 0);
            // Removing the text in the other Runs.
            for (int runPos = found.getBeginRun()+1; runPos <= found.getEndRun(); runPos++) {
              XWPFRun partNext = runs.get(runPos);
              partNext.setText("", 0);
            }                          
          }
        }
      }      
    }
    return count;
  }
```

This method works with search strings spanning over more than one Run. The replaced part gets the style from the first found Run.

Comment: It only works for paragraphs inside tables..it's not working for paragraphs inside document...can you please tell me the solution

Comment: I use this method for whole documents (including header and footer). Normally it should work, but you need to call this method with the paragraph results from the different sections.

Comment: it's not working for the text written in textboxes..any idea how to make it work?

Comment: TextBoxes are very special. Take a look on this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457771/how-to-get-text-from-textbox-of-ms-word-document-using-apache-poi

Answer (score 4):

well, I have done something like that, to replace marks in a word template by specified words...:

```
    public DotxTemplateFiller() {
    String filename = "/poi/ls_Template_modern_de.dotx";
    String outputPath = "/poi/output/output" + new Date().getTime()
            + ".dotx";
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(filename);
        XWPFDocument template = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(file));

        List<XWPFParagraph> xwpfParagraphs = template.getParagraphs();
        replaceInParagraphs(xwpfParagraphs);

        List<XWPFTable> tables = template.getTables();
        for (XWPFTable xwpfTable : tables) {
            List<XWPFTableRow> tableRows = xwpfTable.getRows();
            for (XWPFTableRow xwpfTableRow : tableRows) {
                List<XWPFTableCell> tableCells = xwpfTableRow
                        .getTableCells();
                for (XWPFTableCell xwpfTableCell : tableCells) {
                    xwpfParagraphs = xwpfTableCell.getParagraphs();
                    replaceInParagraphs(xwpfParagraphs);
                }
            }
        }

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputPath));
        template.write(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        //System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // nothing to do ....
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @param xwpfParagraphs
 */
private void replaceInParagraphs(List<XWPFParagraph> xwpfParagraphs) {
    for (XWPFParagraph xwpfParagraph : xwpfParagraphs) {
        List<XWPFRun> xwpfRuns = xwpfParagraph.getRuns();
        for (XWPFRun xwpfRun : xwpfRuns) {
            String xwpfRunText = xwpfRun.getText(xwpfRun
                    .getTextPosition());
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : replacements
                    .entrySet()) {
                if (xwpfRunText != null
                        && xwpfRunText.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                    xwpfRunText = xwpfRunText.replaceAll(
                            entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            xwpfRun.setText(xwpfRunText, 0);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DotxTemplateFiller();
}
```

First I did it for regular paragraphs in the MS Word template and than for paragraphs inside table cells.
Hope it is helpful for you and I hope I understood your problem right... :-)

Best wishes.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your example. 
Is it possible to replace/insert image at a particular location, If possible please give me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to [Josh's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1444061/josh) solution, the map I am building has ended up with over a thousand tags and continues to grow. To cut down on processing, I decided to build a small subset of the tags that I know appear in the paragraph, typically ending up with a map of only one or two tags that I then pass as the Map to the **replaceInParagraphs** method provided above. Also, using the Substitution object to store the substitution text, allows me to add methods into that object (such as formatting) that I can call once the substitution has been completed. Using the subset Map also allows me to know what replacements have been made in any paragraph.

```
private Map<String, Substitution> buildTagList(Map<String, Substitution> replacements, List<XWPFParagraph> xwpfParagraphs, String start, String end) {

    Map<String, Substitution> returnMap = new HashMap<String, Substitution> ();
    for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : xwpfParagraphs) {
        List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();
        // Check is there is a tag in the paragraph
        TextSegment found = paragraph.searchText(start, new PositionInParagraph());
        String runText = "";
        XWPFRun run = null;
        if ( found != null ) {
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            for (int runPos = found.getBeginRun(); runPos < runs.size(); runPos++) {
                run = runs.get(runPos);
                b.append(run.getText(run.getTextPosition()));                    
                runText = b.toString();
            }
            // Now we need to find all tags in the run
            boolean finished = false;
            int tagStart = 0;
            int tagEnd = 0;
            while ( ! finished ) {
                // get the first tag
                tagStart = runText.indexOf(start,tagStart);
                tagEnd = runText.indexOf(end, tagEnd);
                if ( tagStart >= 0 ) {
                    String tag = runText.substring(tagStart, tagEnd + end.length());
                    Substitution s = replacements.get(tag);
                    if (s != null) {
                        returnMap.putIfAbsent(tag,s);
                    }
                }
                else
                    finished = true;
                tagStart = tagEnd + end.length();
                tagEnd = tagStart;
            }
        }
    }
    return returnMap;
}
```