# Replacing a text in Apache POI XWPF not working Extension

Tags: java, apache, ms-word, apache-poi

I am using the last answer which is available in link:
[Replacing a text in Apache POI XWPF not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203087/replacing-a-text-in-apache-poi-xwpf-not-working).
Thanks to Josh.

It is working perfect for almost all scenarios, but sometimes it is not applying the color to the replaced text properly.
am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Runs are funny things. I know that the solution [in this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40226361/6506702) works great to replace sections of paragraphs or parts of runs that have different formatting (bold, embossed, etc) scattered throughout a given paragraph. For my particular use-case, the replace function was able to replace strings mid-run and handle any particular formatting that we were encountering. I didn't personally look at the color, but it appears to have functionality to do so: newRun.setColor(run.getColor());

Note that I originally was using Apache POI 3.11 and the code was giving me a lot of errors like "The method isEmbossed() is undefined for the type XWPFRun". Upgrading to 3.15 solved this.