# How to replace some text in textbox of docx document using Apache POI?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm able to get text of textboxes using code described in answer of  [How to get text from textbox of MS word document using Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457771/how-to-get-text-from-textbox-of-ms-word-document-using-apache-poi)

But i found no way to edit text in a textbox for example to replace some placeholders. Iterate over runs of embeddedPara and setText() does not work. Im using apache poi 3.13.