# Get TextBox Paragraphs from Word Document using Apache POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, xwpf

We use Apache POI to do manipulations of Microsoft Word documents.

So far we're able to access all the required paragraphs (including headers, footers, tables) in a document using the following APIs on `XWPFDocument`

```kotlin
val allBodyElements = bodyElements
    .plus(headerList.flatMap { it.bodyElements })
    .plus(footerList.flatMap { it.bodyElements })

val allParagraphs = allBodyElements.flatMap {
    when (it) {
        is XWPFParagraph -> listOf(it)
        is XWPFTable -> it.rows
            .flatMap { row -> row.tableCells }
            .flatMap { cell -> cell.paragraphs }
        else -> emptyList()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this leaves out the paragraphs contained in TextBoxes. Looking at the underlying `word/document.xml` these TextBoxes are embedded as follows:

```
<w:body>
  <w:p>
    <w:r>
      <mc:AlternateContent>
        <mc:Choice>
          <w:drawing>
            <wp:anchor>
              <a:graphic>
                <a:graphicData>
                  <wps:wsp>
                    <wps:txbx>
                      <w:txbxContent>
                        <!-- DESIRED PARAGRAPH -->
                      </w:txbxContent>
        ...
        </mc:Choice>
          <mc:Fallback>
            <w:pict>
              <v:shape>
                <v:textbox>
                  <w:txbxContent>
                    <!-- DESIRED PARAGRAPH -->
                  </w:txbxContent>
```

Is there a way to get to those paragraphs and receive them as `XWPFParagraph` objects using apache poi, so we can then maniplate them using Java code?

We're currently using apache poi version `4.1.2`

**Edit:** Thanks to the solution offered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25877256/611032 I'm able to extract the paragraphs and read the data, but I don't know how I can save the manually created, manipulated `XWPFParagraph` back to the enclosing paragraph.